# I would like to sort my Animal objects by name

Tags: java

I have created an Animal class:

```
public class Animal{
     private String name; 
     private String color;
     etc...
}
```

I then have an arraylist of animals:

```
ArrayList<Animal> animals = new ArrayList<Animal>();
```

I would like to sort this list of animals by their name alphabetically. Is there a method I need to override within my Animal class? How does this work?

Comment: Research the compareTo() method and override it in your class.

Comment: @TangledUpInBlue nice suggestion. But `Comparator` would probably be better than implementing `Comparable` on `Animal`.

Comment: what have you tried so far? Show the approach you've got and where the problem with that approach is

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no need to change anything in the `Animal` class. Just use a [`Comparator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) (assuming you have a `getName` method that returns the name):

```
animals.sort(Comparator.comparing(Animal::getName));
```

You can also specify the comparator used after extracting value to compare by:

```
animals.sort(Comparator.comparing(Animal::getName, String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER));
```

If you use a java version < 8, use [`Collections.sort`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort-java.util.List-) and a anonymus class as `Comparator` (or use any other way to get a instance of `Comparator` comparing `Animal`s appropriately):

```
Collections.sort(animals, new Comparator<Animal>() {

    @Override
    public int compare(Animal a1, Animal a2) {
        return a1.getName().compareTo(a2.getName()); // or different code comparing the Animals
    }

});
```

Comment: This is a nice solution. I assume this will sort alphabetically in ascending order? What about if I wanted both ascending and descending?

Comment: you should explain this a bit, since OP is obviously new to java and thus definitely not familiar with method-pointers.

Comment: @TalenKylon: [`Comparator.reversed()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#reversed--)

Comment: I don't see the option to use animals.sort. It's not a function of ArrayList?

Comment: @TalenKylon: It's new to `List`s in java 8 (see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#sort-java.util.Comparator-). If you're not using java 8, method pointers also won't work...

Answer (score 0):

You can use streams if you are using java 8 to do the sorting as well.

```
ArrayList<Animal> sortedAnimals = (ArrayList<Animal>) animals.stream().sorted((a1, a2)->a1.name.compareTo(a2.name)).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

The `sorted` takes a Comparator so you can even do something like this:

```
ArrayList<Animal> sortedAnimals = (ArrayList<Animal>) animals.stream().sorted(Comparator.comparing(Animal::getName)).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

As fabian stated if you want more control over the list you can do:

```
ArrayList<Animal> sortedAnimals = animals.stream().sorted(Comparator.comparing(Animal::getName)).collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList<Animal>::new));
```

Comment: I wouldn't rely on the returned list being a `ArrayList`. The javadoc states: *There are no guarantees on the type, mutability, serializability, or thread-safety of the List returned*. Also the suggestion in this case is *if more control over the returned List is required, use toCollection(Supplier)*